# Can I implement BlockingQueue in Java using semaphores in this way?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is this code good implementation of using synchronized mechanism using semaphore in Java, I'm not sure if the length variable is safe because we have 2 methods there, I think that this is the right way, but I need someone to confirm this for me.
Thank you very much for your time!

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> {
    static int length;
    T[] contents;
    int capacity;

    public BlockingQueue(int capacity) {
        contents = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public synchronized void enqueue(T item) throws InterruptedException  {
        while(length == this.capacity) {
            wait();
        }
        contents[length++]= item;
        if(contents.length == 1) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public synchronized T dequeue() throws InterruptedException{
        while(length == 0){
            wait();
        }
        if(length == capacity){
            notifyAll();
        }
        T it = contents[0];
        for(int i=1;i<length;i++)
        {
            contents[i-1]=contents[i]; //shifting left
        }
        length--;
        return it;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `wait` method doing?

Comment: Why does your title ask about semaphores when there is no semaphore in your code?

Comment: Thats the problem but no one is understanding me, i need to create a semaphore with synchronized mechanism using semaphores

Comment: Re, `for(...) { contents[i-1]=contents[i]; //shifting left }` Shifting everything one place to the left _works,_ but it isn't the best way. The best way is to use the array as a [_circular buffer_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a bit more. Why do you need to create a semaphore? Why would it make any sense to _use_ a semaphore to create a semaphore? If your goal is to create a counting semaphore, then why did you write code that implements a blocking queue?

Comment: @SamOrozco, `o.wait()` is a method defined by Java's `Object` class. In a nutshell, `o.wait()` does not return until some other thread subsequently calls `o.notifyAll()` for the same object, `o`. In OP's example, `wait()` (without the `o.`) implicitly means `this.wait()`. In other words, the OP is using the BlockingQueue instance itself (i.e., `this`) as the synchronization object. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html for more about `wait()` and `notifyAll()`.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Awesome! I am surprised I do not know that.

Comment: **`length` should not be `static`** Each `BlockingQueue` instance has its own length, obviously, so how do you even get to the idea that a `static` modifier was appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation looks correct. The structure you have with `length` and `capacity` essentially implements a semaphore. A few items can be improved I believe:

```
if(contents.length == 1) {
    notifyAll();
}
```

If there are multiple producers, this is correct. If there is only one producer, `notify()` should suffice.

Instead of shifting contents, consider allocating capacity+1 and use a circular queue.

Comment: I'm not sure if this way is using synchronized mechanism using Semaphores

Comment: You essentially have a semaphore with `length` and `capacity`.

Comment: There is no guaranty about which thread is woken up by a single `notify()` call, so when there are not only a single producer and a single consumer, using `notifyAll()` will be necessary.

Comment: @Holger, you are correct. I changed the answer accordingly.